# H2O handling of multi-attributed columns

Tags: h2o

How does H2O handle multi-attribute categorical features (i.e. columns with comma-separated values like ('1,2,3', '1,4', '1,2')? Do I need to split those in multiple columns manually (one-hot encoding)?

More specifically assume the data being a tab-separated file as follows:

`col1    col2
1    1,2,3
2    1,4
1    1,2`

Comment: H2O requires tabular data.  Please give an example of what your data looks like in tabular format.  I can't tell if those values represent one cell of your data, or not... I'm not sure how you could have that data in a CSV file unless the cell is a string that looks like this:  `"('1,2,3', '1,4', '1,2')"`.

Comment: I have a tsv (tab-separated file) and one of the columns has comma-separated values. I added the example but you can assume that the data is just a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what those numbers represent.

One-hot encoding involves taking a categorical column and expanding that single column into a group of boolean columns.  The assumption here is that among these boolean columns, a training observation can only belong to one of the columns at a time (that's where the "one" in one-hot comes from) -- only one column can be "active".

If you want to consider `1,2,3` it's own category (rather than three categories), then that's fine if that's how you want to represent the data.  In that case, you can leave the data as-is because H2O will automatically one-hot encode categorical columns under the hood, as long as they are encoded as a factor (aka enum) type.  Assuming that your data frame was just those three rows, then there would be three categories: `1,2,3`, `1,4`, and `1,2`.

If the `1,2,3` value in `col2` means that row 1 is associated with three separate, independent, categories, then you should manually replace `col2` with C binary indicator columns, where C is the total number of categories.  Again, if those three rows represented your whole data frame, then you'd replace `col2` with four columns.  Your new data frame would look like this:

```
col1 col2_1 col2_2 col2_3 col2_4  
1    1      1      1      0
2    1      0      0      1
1    1      1      0      0
```

Comment: Thank you, it makes complete sense, just wondering if I had to do it manually or not.